# svn moved files and now it wont commit

Tags: svn

I moved some files from 1 directory to the other inside visual studio. Now when I try to commit those files, it tells me the other directory is not found (i deleted it). Why does svn still need those directories?

`/svn//trunk/Source/SampleRepoProject.Data/Domains/Interfaces' path not found` <-- this is my previous and deleted directory. The files are moved to:
`/trunk/Source/SampleRepoProject.Domains/Interfaces`

How can I fix this? do I need to go back to all those deleted directories and recreate them?

Using Ankh and tortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you move the files or did you move a folder containing files?

Some IDE's move the .svn folder with the parent folder. This results in **Very Bad Things** as it relates to SVN. As a general rule, I create new folders and move files from the old location to the new without moving the original directory (and, consequently, the .svn folder). Then I delete the old directory.

Comment: I moved the directory contianing the files. So I'm going to delete the .svn folder and see what happens.

Comment: Unless you use the SVN Repair Move option afterwards, they won't be treated as the same file(s) by SVN. This means that if you view the change log on the file, it will only go as far back as when you moved them.

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN has a feature to do this sort of thing safely. Drag the folder to a new location in Windows Explorer using the right-button instead of the left. When you release, a dialog window will pop up and give you the option to SVN Move/Copy the files/folders.